# \lowering \leaders

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex, leaders

I'm using `\leaders` to make a flexible width rule, with the statement `\leaders 0pt plus 1fil\hrule`, but I also want to put text above this line. `\rlap{text}\leaders` works fine, except that the text is very close to the line (which isn't very aesthetic). I like the look of `\underbar{text}`, but I need the line to extend further, so I'm trying to use a more generic `\leaders` to accomplish this. This can't be done with a `\vbox`, as far as I can tell because once in a box that is not the one I'm trying to format, the glue doesn't expand as far as I'd like. So, I'm trying to use `\lower 2pt\leaders`. This fails because `\lower` requires a box as an argument. I had the thought that this might be improved by using a box, but there still has to be a leader statement for the box to be full size, and I can't find a way to set, for example, `\box0`, to be this size (which appears impossible because if the box is already constructed, it's inflexible). I've tried both using `\lastbox` and setting the box directly, but neither works because the box is already constructed.

The final product I imagine will look something like this minimal nonworking example (or maybe it will use a box with depth  or another trick):

```
\line{\hfil\leaders\hbox{\lower2pt\hrule}\hfil}
```

It appears to me that this doesn't obviously violate any part of the TeX boxes-and-glue model, so I expect that it's possible. How can I construct this?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309632/raise-or-lower-hrulefill

Comment: Something like this? `x\makebox[30ex][l]{\leaders\hbox to 1ex{\rule[-1ex]{1ex}{.5pt}}\hfill}x` ?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I am using Plain TeX, but this appears to be similar the solution I built from answers to from that question: `\leaders\vtop{\vskip2in\hrule width 1pt}`. Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with a construction like `\leaders\vtop{\vskip2in\hrule width 1pt}` is that leaders behave differently if used with a box instead of a rule: Instead of always filling the full width, you only get full copies of the box. So it is better to stay with a simple rule.

You can't easily `\lower` a rule, but you can draw it lower fro the beginning. A `\hrule` by default has height 0.4pt, depth 0pt, so to get a rule 2pt lower, you can use

```
abc
\rlap{text}\leaders\hrule height -1.6pt depth 2pt\hfil
\penalty-10000 % Make sure that we actually have some space to fill
some more text
\bye
```

[image]